# get a variable value from a method at runtime with frida

Tags: javascript, android, mobile, reverse-engineering, frida

I'm completely beginner to frida.
I've this final method which belongs to class say X.

[image: click here to see the method code]

I want to extract the value of token variable -> result.getToken() when i hook frida to the android app which contains that class at runtime.

can anyone complete this code with javascript API of frida to get the value of token variable ?

```
Java.perform(function () {
      Java.choose("com.xx.xx", {
        onMatch: function (inst) {
//.................................
        }
      });
      console.log("Done");

    });
```

then i'll use --> frida -U -f "xxx.apk" -l test.js

thank you so much for help !!

Answer (score 2):

Java.choose is in most cases the wrong approach because that only lists the existing instances of a class, so you can only hook a method if there is already an instance loaded into memory.

The common way is to hook the method itself so that all existing and newly created instances use your hook.

```
var classInstanceIdResult = Java.use('com.google.firebase.iid.InstanceIdResult');
var getTokenMethod = classInstanceIdResult.getToken.overload();
// replace the getToken() method with out own implementation
getTokenMethod.implementation = function () {
    // call the orignal method
    var ret = getTokenMethod.call(this);
    // do something with ret
    console.log("Token: " + ret); 
    return ret;
}
```

BTW: The code for hooking a Java method can simply be generated by using [Jadx-Gui](https://github.com/skylot/jadx). Just decompile the APK, select the method and let Jadx generate the Frida code snipped necessary to hook the method (see context menu of the method).

Comment: Hey @Robert can I use the same logic but if the method is not called in the code base instead I to override the Java.use('com.google.firebase.iid.InstanceIdResult') and call the method in the script.

Comment: @mikegrep To my experience hooks are inactive if you call the method yourself from within a Frida script.

Comment: I need to call the method from the app frida to override it for example?

Comment: @mikegrep Sorry but that is nothing you can solve in comments,. Please write a full question describing what app you hook (and the relevant app code) and what you want how you are planning to do so.

Comment: I don't have questions allowance here I will keep in mind to tag you in the question If add one.Thank you

Comment: @mikegrep Everybody has the permission to create new questions. Tagging users in questions or new comments of a new question or answer is not possible. Tagging is only available in comments if the user has already participated in that comment block because user names are not unique.